# How to separate Elastic Beanstalk environments?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-sdk

I am building a service on top of EB which will host several different applications. I want to be able to separate each application so there is no conflicts between them.

For example, I have app1 and app2 both with staging environments. When I try deploy staging env to app2 I get an error `Environment staging already exists` because it exists under app1.

Is there a way to create a completely separate instance for each application in order to avoid these kind of conflicts and also perhaps keep things more secure so that applications don't have access to each others environments?

If it's of any help, I am using the Javascript aws-sdk to create the environment like so:

```
const createElasticBeanstalkEnvironment = async  ({
  applicationName,
  versionLabel,
  environmentName
}) => {
  const describeEnvironmentsCommand = new DescribeEnvironmentsCommand({
    EnvironmentNames: [environmentName],
    ApplicationName: applicationName,
    IncludeDeleted: false
  });

  const { Environments = [] } = await elasticBeanstalkClient.send(describeEnvironmentsCommand);

  const isExistingEnvironment = Environments.length > 0;

  if( isExistingEnvironment ) {
    const updateEnvironmentCommand = new UpdateEnvironmentCommand({
      ApplicationName: applicationName,
      EnvironmentName: environmentName,
      VersionLabel: versionLabel,
      // ...
    });

    return elasticBeanstalkClient.send(updateEnvironmentCommand);
  }

  const createEnvironmentCommand = new CreateEnvironmentCommand({
    ApplicationName: applicationName,
    EnvironmentName: environmentName,
    VersionLabel: versionLabel,
    // ...
  });

  return elasticBeanstalkClient.send(createEnvironmentCommand);
}
```

You can see I am doing a check if the environment exists which if it doesn't, then I create it. My code to `describeEnvironments` returns false because it doesn't exist for that application but when I call `CreateEnvironmentCommand` I get the error that it already exists (albeit under another env)

Comment: What happens if you log / view the versions list from the response to describeApplicationVersionsCommand?  What happens if you use something like "env1:applicationName" and "env2:applicationName" so they don't share the exact same application name?  I suspect your existence check is incorrect but I normally deploy using the console.

Comment: I did consider prefixing each environment with its application name but I figure this may cause additional issues with the length of each environment name being quite lengthy. The application names can already get quite long as they are pulled from the applications github.

Comment: I added a question about testing the version detection -- perhaps the version does exist but your test doesn't catch it?

Comment: Also, you could use shorthand for the different environments like "cluster1:" or "staging":

Comment: They don't share the exact same application name. They share the same environment name and it appears environments are shared between applications from what I can see